Show that the embedding $W^{2,2}(\Omega)$ into $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ is false when $n=2$ and $\Omega=(0,1)^2.$
Let $\Omega=(0,1)^2\subset\mathbb{R}^2.$ By considering the following well-known example
$$u(x,y)=\ln\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)$$
it can be showed that the embedding of $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ into $L^\infty(\Omega)$ is false. My question is that is there any similar example to illustrate that the embedding of $W^{2,2}(\Omega)$ into $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ is false? Any help is appreciated!
